# webmin bind issue- error when i try to start bind

Tags: dns, bind, webmin

I am setting up a domain = `mydomain.com` with 2 nameservers `ns1.mydomain.com` and `ns2.mydomain.com` in Webmin -> `BIND`.

For this, I have registered 2 child nameservers at my domain registrar, and in Webmin->`Bind` I have set up a new zone for this domain.

In this zone, i have specified 2 nameserver records- one each for `ns1` and `ns2`. Also, I have defined 2 address records- one each for `ns1.mydomain.com -> IP Address #1` and for `ns2.mydomain.com -> IP Address #2`

However when I try to start `BIND` in Webmin, I get the following error--

> Failed to start BIND : Starting named: Error in named configuration:
>   zone mydomain.com/IN: has no NS records zone mydomain.com/IN: not
>   loaded due to errors. _default/mydomain.com/IN: bad zone [FAILED]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common reason for this error is missing the trailing periods on domain names.

You might have something similar to

> mydomain.com  IN  NS  ns1.mydomain.com.

In the zone file.  If so, try replaceing with

> mydomain.com. IN  NS  ns1.mydomain.com.

Notice the period after mydomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

See the output of the `hostname` command. In my case the output of the hostname command was `server.mydomain.com`, so there must be an "A record" for you machine's name:

```
server.mydomain.com.     IN      A       10.10.10.10
```

where `server.mydomain.com` is my machine's name `10.10.10.10` is my machine's IP on which I wish to run `bind(dns)`.